# Show hidden class after ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Onclick of button follwing script is running:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo CHILD_URL; ?>/takeaway-orders.php",
    type: 'POST',
    async:false,
    data: 'uniq='+encodeURIComponent(uniq)+'&menu_id='+encodeURIComponent(menuid)+'&quan='+encodeURIComponent(quan)+'&price='+encodeURIComponent(price)+'&tillval_count='+tillval_count,
    success: function(value){


        var resid = value;

        if(tillval_count>0){

            $('.special_request_content').html('<center><img src="'+siteurl+'/images/loader.gif'+'"></center>');
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo CHILD_URL; ?>/special-request.php",
                type: 'POST',
                async:false,
                data: 'id='+encodeURIComponent(resid)+'&menu_det='+encodeURIComponent(menu_det)+'&siteurl='+encodeURIComponent('<?php echo CHILD_URL; ?>')+'&temp_tillval=1&price='+encodeURIComponent(price),
                success: function(value){

                    $('.special_request_content').html(value);
                }
            });

            $('.fader, #special_request').fadeIn();

            $('#btn_skip').click(function(){
                //for the cart
                getcountItem(0);
            });  

        }
        else{

            $('#takeaway .cart_content').html('<center><img src="'+siteurl+'/images/loader.gif'+'"></center>');
            $('#takeaway .cart_content').load("<?php echo CHILD_URL.'/takeaway-cart.php';?>");

            //for the cart
            getcountItem(0);

        }


    }
});
```

I also want to show a class named takeaway on button click. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: So what have you tried. _Or is this a specification_

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.special_request_content').html('<center><img src="'+siteurl+'/images/loader.gif'+'"></center>');
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo CHILD_URL; ?>/special-request.php",
                type: 'POST',
                async:false,
                data: 'id='+encodeURIComponent(resid)+'&menu_det='+encodeURIComponent(menu_det)+'&siteurl='+encodeURIComponent('<?php echo CHILD_URL; ?>')+'&temp_tillval=1&price='+encodeURIComponent(price),
                success: function(value){

                    $('.special_request_content').html(value);
                    $('.takeaway').show();
                }
            });
```